# Custom directive validator calling REST API too slow to set form.$invalid to prevent form submission

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive on a input text field that calls a REST Web Service Api using $http (Restful Resource actually). This web service call typically takes 500ms which by the time the call returns, the user may have hit on the submit button of the form and proceed.

How can i actually prevent that?

Input Field:

```
<input type="text" data-my-user-input-validation="true" data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```

Form:

```
<form name="myform" role="form" data-ng-submit="myform.$valid && submit()" novalidate>
```

Custom directive:

```
app.directive('myUserInputValidation', function(UserInputRestrictionValidationPost) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var validate = attrs.myUserInputValidation;

            if (validate === 'false') {
                // false, don't need to do anything
                return;
            }

            function setAsInvalid(bool) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('userInputValidation', bool);
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                if (!value || value.length == 0) return;

                UserInputRestrictionValidationPost.get({
                    value: value
                }, function(data) {
                    if (data.status === 'OK') {
                        // api return ok
                        setAsInvalid(true);

                    } else {
                        // failure or error
                        setAsInvalid(false);
                    }
                });

                return value;
            })
        }
    }
});
```

**Answer**:

```
app.directive('myUserInputValidation', function(UserInputRestrictionValidationPost) {
  return {
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var validate = attrs.myUserInputValidation;

        if(validate === 'false'){
            // false, don't need to do anything
            return;
        }

        function setAsInvalid(bool) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('userInputValidation', bool); 
        }

        ngModel.$asyncValidators[attrs.name] = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            var value = modelValue || viewValue;

            if(!value || value.length == 0){
                setAsInvalid(true);
                return false;
            }

            return UserInputRestrictionValidationPost.get({ value: value }).$promise.then(function (data) {
                if(data.status === 'OK'){
                    // api ok
                    setAsInvalid(true);
                    return false;

                }else{
                    // failure or error
                    setAsInvalid(false);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        };
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You should use an [async validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators) instead of a parser, and check for [$pending](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$pending) validation to enable/disable your button

Comment: @JBNizet thanks i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose asynchronous validators exists - see $asyncValidators property in ngModelController (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

```
ngModel.$asyncValidators. userInputValidation = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    if (!value || value.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

     return UserInputRestrictionValidationPost.getResultAsPromise(value);
```

Beware of the return value. You have to return promise here.